# How does python interpret "True != True != True"?

Tags: python

I played around with python by writing some nonsense code, and noticed a strange behavior with a line of code I wrote.

```
>>> True != True != True
False
```

I can't wrap my head around why this statement evaluates to False. At first glance I thought python would surround one of the `True != True` with parentheses and then evaluate the whole statement, just like `1 + 1 + 1` is equivalent with `(1 + 1) + 1` or `1 + (1 + 1)`. I tried it in python command line:

```
>>> (True != True) != True
True
>>> True != (True != True)
True
```

But it seems python chooses another strategy to evaluate `True != True != True`, since the statements above both evaluates to True.

So the question is, how does python actually interpret `True != True != True`?

Comment: That's operator chaining. The post I closed this as a dupe of explains this for a closely related issue.

Comment: It is interpreted as `True != True and True != True`.

Comment: Thanks, now I know this strange behavior has a name, and is actually a feature. Easier to Google next time :)